# Image slider on top of my sub menu's

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, slider

Hello i have a problem on my slider http://www.premierchoiceinternet.com/

Image slider on top of my sub menu's

i am using Easy WordPress Parallax Slider.

i have changed the z-index to numerous numbers what i have read on here but for some reason i still cant get the problem resolved if you are able to help i would be more than grateful

I edit the z-index from the eps settings within the admin panel

If i were to post the source code please tell me and i will do so but i dont know if this would be relevant or not

Thank you

Comment: Please include enough code into your question to reproduce the problem, not just link to some webpage.

Comment: I have put in there, that if the code is wanted i will provide it but i cant see the relevancy for the html code when this is wordpress.

Comment: Before asking you must read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .... Why is the code relevant? because just link to an URL that can be down in future make this question useless for future users that can have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You said you already tried it with z-levels.

A common misstake is that you only set your flyout to a z-level and not the slider.

you should use `z-index: 999;` for your flyout and `z-index:1;` for your slider.

i just tried it with firebug and it worked. The flyout is now over the Slider.

Hope this will help you fix it

here is the picture of it:
http://s14.directupload.net/images/141016/bgv6t464.jpg

CSS for the flyout

`#megaMenu.megaMenuHorizontal ul.megaMenu > li.menu-item > ul.sub-menu.sub-menu-1 {
     border-top-left-radius: 2px;
     border-top-right-radius: 2px;
     z-index: 999;
}`

and dont forgett to add the z-index:1; to your slider div

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is move the slider backwards, the simplest way to do so would be by adding `z-index:1;` to the style of slider, so, this line:

```
<div style="max-width: 961px; max-height:301px;" class="eps eps-slide eps-8018 eps-slider">
```

becomes this:

```
<div style="max-width: 961px; max-height:301px;z-index:1;" class="eps eps-slide eps-8018 eps-slider">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="main_menu" class="slidemenu" style="z-index: 999;">
```

This will help you this z-index on the main_menu items will appear above the slide image